# Бывай! still used?

Tags: сленг

Is the word Бывай! still used in contemporary Russian as a way of saying 'goodbye'?

Comment: According to Russian Corpus, the usage in literature is constantly decreasing from maximum in 1963 to almost zero nowadays (see [here](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E1%FB%E2%E0%E9))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this word is in use. But it is rather informal form of "goodbye", for example between good friends

Answer (score 7):

It's one of those semi-obsolete expressions whose usage is either facetious or a personal mannerism.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can use `давай`. This word means handshake.

**Давай, увидимся!**  = Goodbye, see you.

**Бывай, до встречи!** = same as above

Answer (score 3):

Though it has a slightly retro style I guess, it can be used still in inofficial speech  like among good friends and such. Derives from wishing good health when saying goodbye ( i.e. бывай  здоров)